# SalesForce, How do I update a field on one object from using data from another obj?

Tags: salesforce

In SalesForce.  I have 3 objects in an MDR:

```
obj_1 ---< obj_2 >--- Contacts.
```

**Object_1** = meeting types and budget

**Object_2** = attendees at each meeting and money spent on each.

Each time a record involving a contact in obj_2 gets updated, I need to update a field in the contacts object ONLY if the meeting took place in the past year.

How do I do this?  Workflows?  Formulas?

Comment: What kind of update do you need to make on the contacts? Chances are you're going to need to write a trigger for this but it really depends on exactly what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be accomplished by a workflow or an Apex Trigger.

To use a workflow, go to Setup - Create - Workflow & Approvals - Workflow Rules.

- Click 'New rule'
- Select the Obj2 if that's the object that initiates change
- Choose a name for the rule such as 'Update contact on Obj2 update'
- Specify criteria for when workflow should be enacted by selecting 'formula evaluates to true' from a dropbox in the 'Rule Criteria' section and writing in the formula editor something like: DATEVALUE(MeetingDate) > DATE(YEAR(TODAY())-1, MONTH(TODAY()), DAY(TODAY())).
- Click 'Save & Next'
- Choose 'New Field Update' from the 'Add workflow action' dropbox.
- Pick a name for the update action such as 'Update contact budget'
- Specify the field to be updated by selecting from dropboxes below Contact and the field name in Contact such as ContactBudget
- In the 'Specify new field value' section below choose 'Use a formula to set the new value' and enter the name of the field in Obj2 that specifies the budget like Meeting_budget__c
- Save
- Go to Setup - Create - Workflow & Approvals - Workflow Rules again
- Click 'Activate' next to the rule you have just created

Greets,
lenin_ra

Comment: Thanks Lenin_ra. I thought I was specific, but I'll try and clarify. In object 2, the user will specify a contact name (this is the Detail in the MDR relationship from Contact) and populate a dollar amount field. What I need to do is find that contact name in my contacts object and update a field for that contact. How do I do that? Also, as a second question, don't I need to relate the contact name from Obj2 to the contact name in the contacts table? Or is that not necessary. Thanks.

Comment: Ok I have edited the answer to be more specific to your question. This answer assumes that you have the meeting date in Obj2. I can't give you exact code because I don't have your exact specs, but hope this helps! Good luck!

Comment: Thanks lenin_ra. Your solution was very helpful.